# Proving that V is open

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, let $a \in \mathbb{R^n}$, let $s,r \in R$ with $s < r$ and $V = \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : s<||x-a||<r\}$. Prove that V is open.

I'm not too sure how to go about this one here, but for $V$ to be open, for every $a \in V$ there exists some $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq V$.

From what I can see we just need to take some $r \in V$ and show that $B_{\epsilon}(r) \subseteq V$. If this is the case, to prove that this ball is a subset would I actually go about it by taking some element in the ball and finding that element in $V$ or am I just confused about the problem? My definitions are coming from real analysis because I am learning this information from a real analysis text as well.

Comment: What do you think of $V^{c}$?

Comment: it would be all of $\mathbb{R^n}$ minus the ball\disk that we have for V. But that would be closed correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some $x_0\in V$. Then $s<\|x_0-a\|<r$. Now take $\epsilon=\min\{r-\|x_0-a\|,\|x_0-a\|-s\}>0$ and consider $B_\epsilon(x_0)=\{y\in\Bbb R^n:\|y-x_0\|<\epsilon\}$.

If $y\in B_\epsilon(x_0)$ then $\|y-a\|\le\|y-x_0\|+\|x_0-a\|<\epsilon+\|x_0-a\|\le r-\|x_0-a\|+\|x_0-a\|=r$; and $s=s-\|x_0-a\|+\|x_0-a\|\le-\epsilon+\|x_0-a\|<-\|y-x_0\|+\|x_0-a\|\le\|y-a\|$. Therefore $s<\|y-a\|<r$, so $y\in V$.

We conclude $B_\epsilon(x_0)\subseteq V$, so $V$ is open.

Comment: So it seems like you are applying the triangle inequality, but how do you state that $||y-a||$ $\geq ||x_0-a|| - ||y-x_0||$

Comment: Because $\|x_0-a\|\le\|x_0-y\|+\|y-a\|$ and of course $\|x_0-y\|=\|y-x_0\|$

Comment: Would the proof be the same exact format for showing that another set, say E is closed?

Comment: If you mean showing a set like $E=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:r\le \|x-a\|\le s\}$ is closed (the fact that I wrote $r$ first it's not important, I just did it for the sake of clarity), you just have to consider $E^\mathsf c$, which is $V$, since $x\in E^\mathsf c\Leftrightarrow x\notin E\Leftrightarrow r\nleq \|x-a\|\nleq s\Leftrightarrow s<\|x-a\|< r$. Since we know $V$ is open, $E=V^\mathsf c$ is closed.

Comment: Gotcha yeah thats exactly what I meant thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \|x-a\|$ is continuous and $V = f^{-1}\big(]s,r[\big)$. So $V$ is the continuous inverse image of an open set, hence open.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear (you can prove it easily) that the set $G = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-a|| <r \}$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And it is clear that the set $F = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-a|| \le s \}$ is closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, the difference between an open set and closed set ($V = G-F$) is open.